# Search Multiple Values in A Table Column MdBootstrap

Tags: html-table, datatable, mdbootstrap, tablefilter

How can I search/filter multiple values in a single column on the Mdbootstrap data table?
Separating values by comma does not work.

[image]

Comment: This looks like an [MDB Pro](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/data/datatables/) component which requires a paid-for license. If that is the case, you might get an answer here on SO, but you may need to ask on the official [MDB support](https://mdbootstrap.com/support/) forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search multiple values in a column like this:

> Tiger|Ashton in: Name